Sliding-window string/substring algorithm based on endpoints of substring
While there are various known algorithms to check if a string contains a substring (with the simplest but least efficient one being a brute-force sliding window, and one of the most efficient but complex one arguably being KMP), I've uncovered a solution that is almost as efficient as KMP in most cases but is simpler to implement.  (I say "uncovered" rather than "discovered" because surely I'm not the first to discover this.)
Basically, it's a variant/enhancement of the naive sliding-window approach, but with a twist: instead of exhaustively searching each character in the window each time you "slide" it, you just look at the endpoints.
The idea is that, given string s on length m as the string to search to see if it contains string t of length n (where n <= m), you slide the window until you've reached a point at which s[i] and s[i + n] match, respectively, the endpoints of t (i.e., t[0] and t[n - 1]).
Then, and only then, do you iterate through the characters in the middle of t to see if they match the characters in s between i + 1 and i + n.
I've tried it on a wide variety of strings and it appears to perform consistently in O(m) time (specifically, O(2m + n), which is still asymptotically O(m)).
Here is the basic form of the algorithm:
//Return starting index of first occurrence of t in s,
//otherwise -1 if s does not contain t
int FirstIndexOfSubstring(string s, string t)
{
    for (var i = 0; i <= s.Length - t.Length; i++)
    {
        if (t[0] == s[i] && t[t.Length - 1] == s[i + t.Length - 1])
        //Endpoints match:
        {
            var found = true;
            for (var j = 1; j < t.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (t[j] != s[i + j])
                {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

Two questions:

Are there test cases that could "break" this algorithm and cause it
to take O(mn) time like the naive sliding-window approach?
Is this already a well-known algorithm, and if so what is it called?


I don't know if there is a name. S = a^{n-1} b a^{n-1} b a^{n-1} b ... and T = a^n then your algorithm takes \Theta(m n) iterations.

Thanks @pcpthm - how did I miss that? :-O
For now I guess I'll stick with KMP/etc. until I come up with something better
